# How do I take a users input and subtract it in c#

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to finish my lab assignment, this is currently all I have so far.

```
using System;
public class Assignment1A
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Asking user for information
        Console.Write("Please enter a red value. (0-255): ");
        int red = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter a green value. (0-255): ");
        int green = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter a blue value. (0-255): ");
        int blue = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        // inverting numbers


    }

}
```

Summary of what they want the code to do:

> Your task is to:
>
> a) Ask the user to individually enter in three values between 0 to 255
>
> b) Read those three values in
>
> c) Invert each number
>
> d) Display the results
>
> e) Convert the inverted colors to floating point numbers
>
> f) Display those results
>
> Sample Output:
>
> Enter a red value (0-255): 101
>
> Enter a green value (0-255): 67
>
> Enter a blue value (0-255): 33
>
> The inverted color is red=154, green=188, blue=222 With floating
> points, that would be red=0.6039, green=0.7373, blue=0.8706

Comment: You may want to considering using [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-7.0), instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`, as it will allow you capture a non numeric entry without raising an error, thus allowing you to ask the user again for valid input. As your code is now, it will raise an exception if the user enters a value that fails to convert to an `int`.

Comment: `red -= 255;`  (see [Subtraction Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/subtraction-operator))

Comment: Note that you have the (nearly) same two lines of code repeated 3 times. That's an indication that you should consider _refactoring_ your code, putting those two lines in their own method. Then it's easy to chain them to use `int.TryParse`, as has been suggested

Comment: By the way, there's a `byte.TryParse` that will fail for integers over `255`, consider using that (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tryparse?view=net-7.0#system-byte-tryparse(system-string-system-byte@) )

Answer (score 1):

Take this example

```
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    int red, green, blue;
    float red_float, green_float, blue_float;

    // Ask the user to enter in three values between 0-255
    Console.Write("Enter a red value (0-255): ");
    red = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter a green value (0-255): ");
    green = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Enter a blue value (0-255): ");
    blue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // Invert each number
    red = 255 - red;
    green = 255 - green;
    blue = 255 - blue;

    // Display the results
    Console.WriteLine("The inverted color is red={0}, green={1}, blue={2}", red, green, blue);

    // Convert the inverted colors to floating point numbers
    red_float = (float)red / 255;
    green_float = (float)green / 255;
    blue_float = (float)blue / 255;

    // Display those results
    Console.WriteLine("With floating points, that would be red={0:F4}, green={1:F4}, blue={2:F4}", red_float, green_float, blue_float);
  }
}
```

Comment: this code will crash if the user enter non numeric data, should use tryparse